# urlencoding just for arabic text in url NOT for whole URL

Tags: php, urlencode, url-encoding

I have this url: http://www.mywebsite.com/رابط-عربي.html

when using urlencode the whole url encoding and the link is damaged.

what i want to do is urlencoding for arabic text, that mean urlencoding for 'رابط-عربي'

Comment: Did you build this URL in PHP or was the URL given to you? Can you provide the code you are currently using to encode?

Comment: urlencode will convert any character that most be encoded, so this will encode the slashes as well. If you want to urlencode a file name, only encode that part before building the entire url.

Comment: the url given to me ready, NOT building from my side.

Comment: Use this regular expression to extract the arabic text from url and do encode, http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-ereg.php

Comment: Then use `parse_url()` to split it up, instead of encoding without context.